# Why do I get the error -- "Cannot determine file type for '/tmp/test.war'"?

Tags: perl, extract, war, php-ziparchive

I'm on Mac 10.7,5 and using Perl version

```
perl -version
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3)
```

I'm trying to extract a WAR file locally, so I use the command:

```
my $ae = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $downloadedFile );
```

The above line dies with the error:

```
Cannot determine file type for '/tmp/test.war' at ./update_artifact.pl line 57
```

I'm able to unzip the file with the command "unzip /tmp/test.war", so I'm not sure what else I should do to my Perl command to fix my problem.  Any advice is appreciated, -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) doesn't know what the `.war` suffix corresponds to.  It needs some help.  Use `type`:

```
my $ae = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $downloadedFile, type => 'zip' );
```